# Layer black & white video over background so black pixels are transparent in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to blend a video containing black and white animated text over a static background image. I can successfully blend them but no matter what blend mode I use I can't get the effect I want.

I'm looking for an effect similar to Photoshop's 'Add' blend mode where the color values of each pixel are added together. This results in no change where the top layer (video) has black pixels, effectively making the black background appear transparent.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

`ffmpeg -i text.mp4 -loop 1 -i image.jpg \
-filter_complex 'blend=all_mode=addition' -t 1 result.mp4`

I tried all the modes of the `blend` filter but none of them produce this effect. I thought Addition would be the one to work but the resulting video has a pink tint. Maybe there is some mismatch between color channels?

How can I get the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no black pixels from the video need to be shown, you can use

```
ffmpeg -i text.mp4 -loop 1 -i image.jpg \
 -filter_complex '[0]split[m][a];[m][a]alphamerge[keyed]; \
                  [1][keyed]overlay=eof_action=endall' result.mp4
```

The alphamerge filter adds a grayscale version of its 2nd input as the alpha channel to the 1st. The overlay filter does alpha blending of its inputs.

Comment: `[AVFilterGraph @ 02dd9180] No such filter: '[0]split[m][a];[m][a]alphamerge[keyed];'`

Comment: Try double quotes. Check your newline escaping.

Comment: Thanks, I guess changing ' to " fixed it for Windows.